# SQL Server : DDL trigger, controlling table creation

Tags: sql, database, triggers, database-trigger

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I'm creating a DDL trigger like this:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER  tName ON database FOR CREATE_TABLE
as
  print 'A table has been created'
```

Can I get that table that has been created !?

Something like inserted or deleted in the normal table triggers ?!

Comment: May I know.. any special reason to know tabel create message?

Comment: I jut want to know the "just created" table name, so I can keep track of all the tables created in the DB "dynamically created by T-SQL"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_TABLES
ON DATABASE 
AFTER 
    CREATE_TABLE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME

    SELECT 
        @TABLE_NAME = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','SYSNAME')

    ...


END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to extract it from the CommandText in the `EventData()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187909.aspx